# How to stream PCM audio to a speakers both on mac and linux in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, audio, raspberry-pi, apple-m1, audio-streaming

**Context:**

I'm developing audio app on Node.js for RPI on Rapsberry PI OS Lite (Debian, no GUI), and I need the way of playing mp3 files in the Node.js env from https with the ability to pause/resume the playback. I need this to be working on Mac M1 (dev/debug) and on the RPI.

Surprisingly for me, I didn't find any working audio player for mac/linux that would solve this out of the box (spent a few hours searching and trying different options).

**Possible solution**

I am trying to implement the playback with the following approach: mp3 -> PCM stream -> speaker, that looks relatively straight-forward, smth like this:

```
import https from "https";
import prism from "prism-media";
import Speaker from "speaker";

decoder = new prism.FFmpeg({...});
speaker = new Speaker({...});

play(url) {
  this.stream = https.get(url, (response) => {
    response.pipe(this.decoder).pipe(this.speaker);
  });
}

pause() {
  this.decoder.unpipe(this.speaker);
}


resume() {
  this.decoder.pipe(this.speaker);
}
```

**The problem**

The *speaker* package [fails to install](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker/issues/83) on Mac M1 with Node v21.7.

Then I found [this fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker-arm64) of the [arm64 support](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker/pull/109#issuecomment-658658406), which also fails to install with:

```
...
npm ERR! ../deps/mpg123/src/mpg123app.h:14:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
...
```

Then I found the audio-speaker package that looks promissing, but it also fails on initialisation [with this](https://github.com/audiojs/audio-speaker/issues/63).

I don't give it up, but I am afraid I am running out of options I can come up with on my own.
I would appreciate any feedback.